# Hibernate/Java: retrieving primary key always returns zero

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, maven

I am trying to use Hibernate with MySQL. Here is some more information about my software:

IDE: InteliJ IDEA
Spring MVC
TomCat Server
Maven
Hibernate

I've got a Family entity, and a User entity. Each user is going to be part of a 'family unit', so I need to be able to retrieve the family id of each user to show a family tree of sorts. However, no matter what I do, I can't get the familyId to return anything besides 0 or null. Here's the code I have so far:

Home Controller

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/dashboard/admin/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String newAdmin(@RequestParam("famName") String famName,
                       @RequestParam("fName") String fName,
                       @RequestParam("lName") String lName,
                       @RequestParam("email") String email,
                       @RequestParam("password") String password,
                       Model model){

    FamiliesEntity family = newFamily(famName);
    UsersEntity user = newAdmin(fName,lName,email,password,family.getFamilyid());

    model.addAttribute("family", family);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);

    return "adminDashboard";
}

@RequestMapping ("/register/user")
public String registerUser(){
    return "newUser";
}

private FamiliesEntity newFamily(String famName) {
    Configuration configurationObject = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configurationObject.buildSessionFactory();
    Session adminSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction familyTransaction = adminSession.beginTransaction();
    FamiliesEntity newFamily = new FamiliesEntity();

    newFamily.setName(famName);

    // returns 0, should return 0
    System.out.println("before save :" + newFamily.getFamilyid());

    int testvalue = (Integer)adminSession.save(newFamily);

    // both return 0, should return 30-something
    System.out.println("after save :" + newFamily.getFamilyid());
    System.out.println("after save :" + testvalue);

    familyTransaction.commit();

    // both return 0, should return 30-something
    System.out.println("after commit :" + newFamily.getFamilyid());
    System.out.println("after commit :" + testvalue);

    return newFamily;
}
```

FamilyEntity

```
package com.grandcircus.spring.models;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Class description
 *
 * @author Sarah Guarino
 * @version 1.0
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "families", schema = "checkin", catalog = "")
public class FamiliesEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int familyid;
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "familyid", nullable = false)
    public int getFamilyid() {
        return familyid;
    }

    public void setFamilyid(int familyid) {
        this.familyid = familyid;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        FamiliesEntity that = (FamiliesEntity) o;

        if (familyid != that.familyid) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(that.name) : that.name != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = familyid;
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

FamilyEntity.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.grandcircus.spring.models.FamiliesEntity" table="families" schema="checkin">
        <id name="familyid">
            <column name="familyid" sql-type="int(10) unsigned zerofill"/>
        </id>
        <property name="name">
            <column name="name" sql-type="varchar(45)" length="45"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that Hibernate generated my FamilyEntity.hbm.xml incorrectly. Where it had:

```
    <id name="familyid">
        <column name="familyid" sql-type="int(10) unsigned zerofill"/>
    </id>
```

It should have had:

```
    <id name="familyid" type="int" column="familyid">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
```

in the second example, use int instead of int(10). column should be the column name, the same value you see in "name='' " in the first example.

Comment: The <generator> tag saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate can get access to you data by fields and getter methods annotations.

Hibernate will pick the access method based on the location of the @Id annotation and you cannot mix them. If you annotate a field with @Id, annotations on methods will be ignored and visa versa.

So you should set up your annotations either above the fields or above the getter methods.

Move

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
```

to getter

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name = "familyid", nullable = false)
    public int getFamilyid() {
        return familyid;
    }
```

And actually you don't need FamilyEntity.hbm.xml

Use

```
SessionFactory  factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().
                   configure().
                   //addPackage("com.xyz") //add package if used.
                   addAnnotatedClass(FamiliesEntity.class).
                   buildSessionFactory();
```

I hope it helps)

Comment: It didn't resolve the issue but it's still good info to have. Thank you! I wish I could upvote you, but I'm not able to yet.